# Issue with pine editor cursor offset

Tags: linux, cursor, editor, pine-script

In the Pine editor, the cursor if offset to the right by some characters.  In my case, it is 5 characters at the beginning so a line, and over 20 at the end of the line.  It seems that the spacing the cursor thinks it needs for a character is about 10% more than the spacing it should be using.  I have tried KDE, Xfce, metacity, etc., and disabled/enabled GTK stuff in Chrome, and various browsers, but all exactly the same.

I have seen several similar complaints regarding GTK/Linux web editors so it is necessarily a Pine editor issue, but I have no problem with every other web-based editor, which is why I am asking here , as it is only a problem for me with the Tradeview's Pine editor.

Are there any users here who have experienced this same issues, and if so, was there a solution?  In my case, I am using Arch/Manjaro Linux.

Alternativley, is there a reccomended editor for Pine?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your terminal and/or font that you have installed, rather than a specific issue with Pine.

Comment: Seems it may be an issue with the Ace editor and Noto fonts  

(according to https://gist.github.com/gnuns/75badb58795ac78dc96a0ebaf5aa68f5)

Comment: FWIW, the problem does not exist in Firefox.  Stupidly, that was one browser I did not test previously :/